# Calculate consecutive days posting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a simple Ruby on Rails app I'm trying to calculate the number of consecutive days a User has posted. So for example, if I have posted each of the last 4 days, I'd like to have on my profile "Your current posting streak is 4 days, keep it up!" or something like that.

Should I be keeping track of the "streaks" in one of my models, or should I be calculating them elsewhere? Not sure where I should do it, or how to properly do so, so any suggestions would be wonderful.

I'm happy to include any code you'd find useful, just let me know.

Comment: Personally, I would calculate the streak length every time the profile page was requested.

Comment: What database? MySQL? Postgres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best way, but here's one way to do it in SQL. First, take a look at the following query.

```sql
SELECT
  series_date,
  COUNT(posts.id) AS num_posts_on_date
FROM generate_series(
       '2014-12-01'::timestamp,
       '2014-12-17'::timestamp,
       '1 day'
     ) AS series_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.created_at::date = series_date
GROUP BY series_date
ORDER BY series_date DESC;
```

We use `generate_series` to generate a range of dates starting on 2014-12-01 and ending 2014-12-17 (today). Then we do a LEFT OUTER JOIN with our `posts` table. This gives us one row for every day in the range, with the number of posts on that day in the `num_posts_on_date` column. The results looks like this ([SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a7c9/22/0)):

```
 series_date                     | num_posts_on_date
---------------------------------+-------------------
 December, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 |                 1
 December, 16 2014 00:00:00+0000 |                 1
 December, 15 2014 00:00:00+0000 |                 2
 December, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 |                 1
 December, 13 2014 00:00:00+0000 |                 0
 December, 12 2014 00:00:00+0000 |                 0
 ...                             |               ...
 December, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |                 0
```

Now we know there's a post on every day from Dec. 14–17, so if today's Dec. 17 we know the current "streak" is 4 days. We could do some more SQL to get e.g. the longest streak, as [described in this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/detecting-runs-or-streaks-in-your-data), but since we're only interested in the length of the "current" streak, it'll just take a small change. All we have to do is change our query to get only the first date for which `num_posts_on_date` is `0` ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a7c9/24/0)):

```sql
SELECT series_date
FROM generate_series(
       '2014-12-01'::timestamp,
       '2014-12-17'::timestamp,
       '1 day'
     ) AS series_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.created_at::date = series_date
GROUP BY series_date
HAVING COUNT(posts.id) = 0
ORDER BY series_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And the result:

```
 series_date
---------------------------------
 December, 13 2014 00:00:00+0000
```

But since we actually want the number of days since the last day with no posts, we can do that in SQL too ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a7c9/26/0)):

```sql
SELECT ('2014-12-17'::date - series_date::date) AS days
FROM generate_series(
       '2014-12-01'::timestamp,
       '2014-12-17'::timestamp,
       '1 day'
     ) AS series_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.created_at::date = series_date
GROUP BY series_date
HAVING COUNT(posts.id) = 0
ORDER BY series_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Result:

```
 days
------
    4
```

There you go!

Now, how to apply it to our Rails code? Something like this:

```ruby
qry = <<-SQL
  SELECT (CURRENT_DATE - series_date::date) AS days
  FROM generate_series(
         ( SELECT created_at::date FROM posts
           WHERE posts.user_id = :user_id
           ORDER BY created_at
           ASC LIMIT 1
         ),
         CURRENT_DATE,
         '1 day'
       ) AS series_date
  LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = :user_id AND
                           posts.created_at::date = series_date
  GROUP BY series_date
  HAVING COUNT(posts.id) = 0
  ORDER BY series_date DESC
  LIMIT 1
SQL

Post.find_by_sql([ qry, { user_id: some_user.id } ]).first.days # => 4
```

As you can see, we added a condition to restrict results by user_id, and replaced our hard-coded dates with a query that gets the date of the user's first post (the sub-select inside the `generate_series` function) for the beginning of the range and `CURRENT_DATE` for the end of the range.

That last line is a little funny because `find_by_sql` will return an array of Post instances, so you then have to call `days` on the first one in the array on to get the value. Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```ruby
sql = Post.send(:sanitize_sql, [ qry, { user_id: some_user.id } ])
result_value = Post.connection.select_value(sql)
streak_days = Integer(result_value) rescue nil # => 4
```

Within ActiveRecord it can be made a little cleaner:

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  USER_STREAK_DAYS_SQL = <<-SQL
    SELECT (CURRENT_DATE - series_date::date) AS days
    FROM generate_series(
          ( SELECT created_at::date FROM posts
            WHERE posts.user_id = :user_id
            ORDER BY created_at ASC
            LIMIT 1
          ),
          CURRENT_DATE,
          '1 day'
        ) AS series_date
    LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = :user_id AND
                             posts.created_at::date = series_date
    GROUP BY series_date
    HAVING COUNT(posts.id) = 0
    ORDER BY series_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
  SQL

  def self.user_streak_days(user_id)
    sql = sanitize_sql [ USER_STREAK_DAYS_SQL, { user_id: user_id } ]
    result_value = connection.select_value(sql)
    Integer(result_value) rescue nil
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def post_streak_days
    Post.user_streak_days(self)
  end
end

# And then...
u = User.find(123)
u.post_streak_days # => 4
```

The above is untested, so it'll likely take some fiddling to make it work, but I hope it points you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly detailed and insightful response, it seems to be working in my limited testing thus far!

Answer (score 3):

I would create two columns in the user model. "streak_start", and "streak_end" which are timestamps.

Assuming posts belong to a user.

**Post Model**

```
after_create :update_streak  
def update_streak
    if self.user.streak_end > 24.hours.ago
        self.user.touch(:streak_end)
    else
        self.user.touch(:streak_start)
        self.user.touch(:streak_end)
    end
end
```

Personally I would write it like this:

```
def update_streak
    self.user.touch(:streak_start) unless self.user.streak_end > 24.hours.ago
    self.user.touch(:streak_end)
end
```

Then to determine a user's streak.

**User Model**

```
def streak
    # put this in whatever denominator you want
    self.streak_end > 24.hours.ago ? (self.streak_end - self.streak_start).to_i : 0
end
```

Comment: This is really brittle.

Comment: I would argue that this is the most flexible, cleanest solution. Other answers that use pure SQL hide the name of the `posts` table in a string, along with column names and other information. With this solution, you can have *multiple* tables maintain streaks, not just one. For example, if you decide adding a `PrivateMessage` should extend your streak, you'll just need to add the `update_streak` method in the `PrivateMessage` model. Thanks for this answer - it's working for me! :)

Comment: One more bonus of this method: You don't have to touch every single record in the `posts` table to access the streak (which would be a problem if you accessed it often). Instead, it's nicely cached, more or less, as a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Another nice solution can be found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22142424/3002847). With this code you can see consecutive days also for yesterday, even if your users at that moment doesn't have any posts today. It will motivate users tо continue their streak.

```
def get_last_user_posts_steak
    qry = <<-SQL
        WITH RECURSIVE CTE(created_at)
        AS
        (
           SELECT * FROM 
           (
              SELECT created_at FROM posts WHERE posts.user_id = :user_id AND ( created_at::Date = current_date 
              OR created_at::Date = current_date - INTERVAL '1 day' )
              ORDER BY created_at DESC
              LIMIT 1
           ) tab
           UNION ALL

           SELECT a.created_at FROM posts a
           INNER JOIN CTE c
           ON a.created_at::Date  = c.created_at::Date  - INTERVAL '1 day' AND a.user_id = :user_id
           GROUP BY a.created_at
        ) 
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE;
    SQL

    sql = sanitize_sql [ qry, { user_id: user.id } ]
    result_value = connection.select_value(sql)
    return Integer(result_value) rescue 0
end

Result = Post.get_last_user_posts_steak(current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Andrew's answer will work. Admittedly, I may be overthinking this solution, but if you would like an SQL-focused solution that doesn't require maintaining streak columns, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *, COUNT(diff_from_now)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        p1.id,
        p1.user_id,
        p1.created_at,
        (DATEDIFF(p1.created_at, p2.created_at)) AS diff,
        DATEDIFF(NOW(), p1.created_at) AS diff_from_now
    FROM
        posts p1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        posts
    ORDER BY created_at DESC) p2 ON DATE(p2.created_at) = DATE(p1.created_at) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    WHERE
        (DATEDIFF(p1.created_at, p2.created_at)) IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY (DATEDIFF(p1.created_at, p2.created_at)) DESC , created_at DESC) inner_query
GROUP BY id, sender_id, created_at, diff, diff_from_now, diff_from_now
HAVING COUNT(diff_from_now) = 1
where user_id = ?
```

In a nutshell, the innermost query calculates the date difference between that post, and the next consecutive post, while also calculating that post's difference from the current date. The outer query then filters anything where the date difference sequence is not increasing by one day.

**Please note:** This solution has been tested only in MySQL, and while I see you indicated Postgres as your database, I don't quite have the time right now to properly change the functions to those used by Postgres. I will properly flesh this answer out shortly, but I thought it might be beneficial to see this sooner rather than later. This note will also be removed when I update this post.

You should be able to execute this as raw SQL. It is also possible to convert this to Active Record, which I will likely do when I update this post.